# How to reliably post multiple values set in a single hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, encoding

I end up with an array filled with values like this:

```
var results = ['This is result 1',
               'This is result 2. It could have a comma, semicolon or anything;',
               'This is result 3'
              ];
```

All of the results will be stored in a single hidden field and then parsed on the server, but I feel like this could be problematic:

```
$('#hidden_results').val(results.join(','));
```

What would be a more elegant approach to doing something like this? I need to avoid potential parsing issues when this field is processed on the server.

Thanks!

Comment: What framework are you using on the server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serialize the array using JSON.

```
$('#hidden_results').val(JSON.stringify(results));
```

To deserialize the value on the client side you can do this:

```
var results = JSON.parse($('#hidden_results').val());
```

To deserialize the value in PHP, use [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: Both the easiest and simplest answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this :

```
results = '"' + results.map(function (v) {
    return v.replace(/,/g, ',,');
}).join('","') + '"';
```

Then you can deserialize like this :

```
results = results.slice(1, -1).split('","').map(function (v) { 
    return v.replace(/,,/g, ','); 
});
```

You can easily find PHP equivalents to Javascript functions.